# TypeORM - run specific migration

Tags: typeorm

I know `typeorm migration:run` to run all migration files, but some time I want run a file like `insert` file, or a modified file. But i can't find any doc for that. How to do that thanks.

Comment: when you change a column or insert new rows, you should generate a new migration file rather than modify the old version migration, because migrations stands for a history and they are linear. If you changed one of them and run, your rollback process will be totally broken, and next time the other developers will face error.

Comment: A workaround could be to remove all other migration from the folder and keeping the migrations which you want to run.After execution bring back the removed migrations.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to seed the database with data you shouldn't use migrations.
Migrations' purpose is to create the database's structure, This is why migrations are executed serially, therefore running a single migration non-serially misses the point.

For database seeding with typeorm you can use [typeorm cli query](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#run-any-sql-query), you can create a script that read the SQL from a file.

For example in a node.js app & bash:

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
...,
"typeorm": "npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli --config ormconfig-migrations.ts",
"db:seed": "bash scripts/db-seed.sh"
}
```

db-seed.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
query=""

for filename in sql/seed/*.seed.sql; do
 query=${query}"$(< ${filename})";
done

npm run typeorm query "${query}";
```

Pay attention there is a [bug](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6612) in this solution, there is always an error thrown from the logger typeorm uses - ignore it. it doesn't relate to the db operation, and does not represent the success of the process.

A migration file that was shared with others shouldn't be modified, in this case, create a new migration.
If that file wasn't shared and is in development, you can run `migration:revert` as many as you need, then modify and run `migration:run` again.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. You can see the docs of the migration with

```
typeorm migration:run -h
```

During development you can locally change your connection settings, e.g. change the path to the migration files in your *ormconfig.json* to match only your file.

```
"migrations": [
    "src/db/migration/**/yourmigration.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

For running a specific migration my solution is in `ormconfig.js` add:

```
module.exports = {
...
   migrations: [process.env.DB_MIGRATION_DIR || 'src/database/migrations/*.ts'],
...
}
```

and now use `DB_MIGRATION_DIR=path/to/migration.ts npm run typeorm migration:run` run your specific migration

Another tip for force re-running a migration, but might need some customization for connection string variables - add in your package.json:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "migration:rerun": "psql postgresql://$DB_USER@localhost:5432/$DB_NAME -c "delete from migrations where name like '%$SEED_NAME%';" && DB_MIGRATION_DIR='$DB_MIGRATION_DIR' npm run typeorm migration:run"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we can run any migration particular with cli, but we can run it through query runner. please refer the following code:

```
 const connection: Connection = getConnection();
const queryRunner: QueryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();

//createDatabase16413343434 is class/migration generated from cli
const createDatabase = new createDatabase16413343434();
 await createDatabase.up(queryRunner);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

One can write custom code to run one migration like inserting a record or just creating/ deleting a single table kind of things. typeorm provides "QueryRunner" which basically run queries in the background. So just create a file with the code given following  [code to write custom single migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYIiV.png)

[code to run migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knnjD.png)